# if integral exist, then the Tonelli's theorem result theorem hold

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

[image]

In my opinion, I think that the last words have a question.
Since we want to prove that  $$\int\left(\int  f(x,y) dy\right)dx=\int\int  f(x,y) dxdy$$
but the substraction $$\int\left(\int  f^+ dy\right)dx-\int\left(\int  f^- dy\right) dx..(2)$$
cannot implies it equal to
$$\int\left(\int  (f^+-f^-) dy\right)dx$$
since $$\int  f^+ dy$$ are not necessary be integrable,
I have some idea:
we need to show $\int  f^+ dy$ $\ge$ $\int  f^- dy$ ,then we get $(2)$ equal $$\int\left(\left(\int (f^+)-\int  (f^-)\right) dy\right)dx$$
and also I need to show that $$\int  f dy$$ exist ,then the theorem follows.

Can someone point out some hint to explain this consequence int the textbook?

thanks.

Comment: I think that $\int f^+dy$ can not be integrable at all, but this  is not a problem, since the sum (or substraction) of two Lebesgue integrals is well defined as long they are not both 'infinite integrable' with different signs (or same signs).  So in that case you are allowed to write $\int g_1(x) dx -\int g_2(x) dx= \int g_1(x)- g_2(x) dx$ for $g_1(x)=\int f^+(x,y) dy$ and $g_2$ analogously for $f^-$, since $g_2$ is integrable.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume $\int \int f = +\infty$ then necessarily (as $f^+\geq 0$ and $f^-\geq 0$) $\int \int f^+ = +\infty$ and $\int \int f^-$ finite otherwise we arrive at an inconsistency of the type $+\infty - +\infty$

On the other hand as $f^-$ is integrable on I, then since $f^- \geq 0$, $\int_ {I_2} f^-$ is integrable on $I_1$, but the last integral could take the value $+\infty$ on a set of measure zero.

It is enough to modify these values not to eventualy encounter a problem with $\int f^+ - \int f^-$ in cases where $\int f^+ = +\infty$.

But in the case where $\int \int f^+ = +\infty$, do we have
$\int\left (\int f^+ - \int f^- \right) = \int \int f^+ - \int \int f^-$

We can take an increasing sequence $(f^+_n)$ of measurable functions converging to $f^+$ and show this equality by applying the monotone convergence theorem, the sequences $(f_n^+ -f^-)$ and $(\int f_n^+ - \int f^-)$ being increasing ...